# DI woes with Mass Transit consumer and Simple Injector

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, simple-injector, masstransit

I have a .net core web api which I have been trying to add a Mass Transit consumer to. The consumer has a dependency on a service. The service is registered with the Simple Injector container.

```
container.Register<IMyService, MyService>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

The service in turn has a dependency on a DBContext which was added using the IServiceCollection.AddDbContext and then has been cross wired thus :

```
Container.CrossWire<MyDbContext>(app);
```

I have added the service to the constructor of the consumer like so :

```
public AddMyCommandConsumer(IMyService service)
{
    _service = service;                
}
```

So my next step was to setup the end point. First try thus :

```
cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, options.MyQueue, e =>
{
    var service = container.GetService<IMyService>();
    e.Consumer(() => new AddMyCommandConsumer(service));
}
```

Failed dismally due to the fact that the service is Async scoped. Simple Injector didn't like that. So after a bit of digging, I came up with a second iteration :

```
cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, options.MyQueue, e =>
{
    using (AsyncScopedLifestyle.BeginScope(container))
    {
        var service = container.GetService<IMyService>();
        e.Consumer(() => new AddMyCommandConsumer(service));
    }
}
```

This get's a bit further, with the consumer being created, and the consume method being called, but as soon as I use the service and the DBContext is needed, simple injector complains that the DBContext has been disposed. If I remove the **using** statement then it works, but the scope is never disposed.

I then had a look at the MassTransit.SimpleInjector nuget package. There is no documentation and no examples that I can find, but after a bit of digging I came up with this :

```
var consumerFactory = new ScopeConsumerFactory<AddMyCommandConsumer>(new 
    SimpleInjectorConsumerScopeProvider(container));                        
e.Consumer(consumerFactory);
```

Mass Transit attempts to create the consumer, but this time it fails as Simple Injector is unable to create the service even though it is registered in the container. This last attempt is a little bit of a guess as I said above, there is no documentation or examples. To be honest I think even if I got this working, I'd end up with the same problem with the DBContext as above.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can find usage examples in the unit tests: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/Containers/MassTransit.Containers.Tests/SimpleInjector_Specs.cs  -- sadly the dev who contributed the extension package never added a page to the docs

Comment: I won’t add it as ana answer, but seriously, .NET Core already have a working service locator. Overall I personally prefer using the composition root, but the MS DI is fine and you must use it anyway. What’s the point of using two containers, one on top of the other?

Comment: Alexey, I think you're probably 100% right. It's just when you start out using .net core, the documentation and various blog posts subliminally suggest the Microsoft DI container should be replaced. In hindsight I don't think you probably need to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a reference to the MassTransit.SimpleInjector package, and then in your receive endpoint, configure the consumer using:

```
cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("queue_name", e =>
{
    e.Consumer<AddMyCommandConsumer>(container);
});
```

The extension method will properly configure the scope provider and add the consumer factory to pull from the container. Your consumer should be registered as AsyncScoped, so that it properly handles async/await (MT is heavily built on the TPL).

```
container.Register<AddMyCommandConsumer>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

Also, I think there is a container option to specify async lifestyle as the default.

```
container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AsyncScopedLifestyle();
```

Hopefully this helps, any other error you get is likely related to how your service or DbContext are registered.

Comment: "Your consumer should be registered as AsyncScoped". Are consumers reused or requested multiple times within a single scope? Otherwise, the default Transient lifestyle will do just fine. Registering root types as scoped typically only complicates your configuration.

Comment: Yes that works, and is a clean solution. My consumer is not clogged with container or async related code, and the container looks after injecting everything needed. The consumer must be async scoped as the service is async scoped (and so it the repository it depends on). They can and are used multiple times within a scope, so I think async scoped is the way to go. If the service is async scoped, then the consumer must be also.

Comment: Agree with @Steven , if you make it Scoped, you'll be forced to make all consumer dependencies scoped as well.

Comment: @Alexander this is actually not the case any longer in v5. In v5 you can now inject transients into scoped components without getting a Lifestyle Mismatch warning.

Comment: @Steven good to know that v5 is finally out! But I guess the rule should be the same - register everything as transient unless you _need_ it to be scoped or singleton. Like consumers - looks like they are called once per message.

Comment: I agree with your assessment.

Comment: I know this comment is 4 years later. But struggling with SimpleInjector - Masstransit and creating good integration tests for consumers. Now MassTransit 8 has released and MassTransit.simpleinjector nuget is depricaded. Curios how Masstransit will handle support for DI and WebApplicationFactory (xUnit/dotnet core)? Haven't found any good solutions how that has been implemented...

Comment: MassTransit has a complete sample on using the web application factory: https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-WebApplicationFactory